# Posting to Facebook App page wall as the App Page in python

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I am trying make a post on my apps page wall as if it is coming from the app page (not another user) After researching I seem to find no solution that actually works!

I have tried to follow the documentation here:

I then get my 'access_token_page' by getting it from:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Then using the facebook python api I try:

```
graph1 = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token_page)
graph1.put_wall_post(fbmessage, attachment, profile_id=APP_PAGE_ID)
```

However this just returns the following facebook error:

```
*** GraphAPIError: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

Any ideas on what I am missing? Remember, I am looking to have the App Page make a post to itself, not have a post be generated from another username.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What you had done is using **App Access Token** to publish to page.

You should using **Page Access Token** to post on page admin behalf instead. **User Access Token** is works too but it's a bug as reported at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/647340981958249, so it's not recommended to use **User Access Token** by this time of writing.

As documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens:

> Page Access Tokens
>
> To perform the following operations as a Page, and not the current
>   user, **you must use the Page's access token**, not the user access token
>   commonly used for reading Graph API objects. This access token can be
>   retrieved by issuing an HTTP GET to /USER_ID/accounts with the
>   manage_pages permission.

More info about different type of access token please visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Answer (score 1):

Try Django Facebook:
https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook
This will deal with many of your API problems.

You need the page access token, see here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
Ask for manage_pages as an extra permission

After getting that setup, simply do:

```
user_graph = OpenFacebook(user_access_token)
response = user_graph.get('me/accounts')
# turn the response to a dict, and be sure to get the page you want
page_access_token = response['data'][0]['access_token']
graph = OpenFacebook(page_access_token)
graph.set('me/feed', message='helloworld')
```

You can find more docs here:

http://django-facebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/open_facebook/api.html